# Select rows from column that have value 9

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trying to select from column where row has record number 9. It seems to be easy task but I can't figured it out.
Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = 9 LIMIT 3
```

and this

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category LIKE '%9%' LIMIT 3
```

and few more but none return proper results.

UPDATE:

In table `posts` I have

```
post_id
....
category
```

Category has values `1`, `2` etc.
I want to show on site only this posts that have value 9 in category column `category=9`

UPDATE 2:

This is the post table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`post_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`post_text` longtext NOT NULL,
`post_author` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`category` int(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

ALTER TABLE `posts`
ADD CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `category` (`cat_id`);
```

and data for example

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `post_title`, `post_text`, `post_author`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 'title', 'LOREM IPSUM', 'Athor', 1),
```

UPDATE 3: full code that I trying to use

```
 require_once 'misc/database.inc.php'; 
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    function truncate($text, $chars = 180) {
            $text = $text." ";
            $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
            $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
            $text = $text." ...";
            return $text;
    }
    $query2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '7' LIMIT 3");
    foreach ($query2 as $row) {
        echo '<li class="col-md-12 col-sm-4"> 
              <div class="single-post">
              <h4>'.$post['post_title'].'</h4>   
              <p>'.truncate($row['post_text']).'</p>
              <a href="#" style="float: right;"> More -></a>
              </div>
              </li>';                
    }                          
    Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the question. Could you provide some sample data and the results you're trying to get?

Comment: I have updated a little my question. Is it more clear now or still not?

Comment: Is category an integer or a string? If it's a string you should try `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category = '9' LIMIT 3`

Comment: What's wrong with the output from your queries?

Comment: Using WHERE category=9 is sufficient. What is your data in the table? What is the data type of category column?

Comment: It's return post with `ID=1` 3 times.. i.e. first row from column three times..

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts WHERE category = 9`

Comment: @JasonPaddle . . . You would appear to have duplicates in the table.  `where category = 9` will return each row only once.

Comment: @Jason Paddle well It can return post with id = 1 , you are doing the where for category, not for id .... ?

Comment: @Wouter still same result it returns 3 times the first id. Gordon I don't think I understand you.?

Comment: But id=1 has category value 1 .. not 9. I want to select only those with category value 9

Comment: But one way or another , just show us the table with sample data, would be really helpfull

Comment: Is this the entire query? Or is it part of a longer query that refers to more than one table? This problem smells to me like a `JOIN` combinatorial explosion.

Comment: @JasonPaddle I think Gordon means that you have multiple rows with ID 1

Comment: Column `category` in `post` table corresponding to table `category` column `cat_id` where are stored categories names.

Comment: Well when i create your table , insert the data and run the select it will return excatly what i want...

Comment: I get every time different result. It's like I using `RAND()` it doesn't have any senses in the results.

Comment: I have updated full code that I trying to use

Comment: how many records do you have in that table? You should show us proofs of your data with cat id = 9. because you use `1` in your `INSERT` and `7` in your real php code `SELECT`. it seems you are really jumping around the code and data but not control and manage them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm you use $post['post_title'] in the loop (ForEach)
try to use $row->post_title

reference https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/results.html